# How to fill edit form's nested inputs ? ( simple_fields_for ) Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form, simple-form-for

i have a `nested` form. `New` method works well. But in my `edit` form nested inputs are empty. Here is my form :

```
  <%= simple_form_for @company , url: admin_company_path(@company) do |f| %>
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :licence do |p| %>
         <%= p.input_field  :number  %>  
        <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

my company model :

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :licence
  has_one :licence , inverse_of: :company , :dependent => :destroy
```

my licence model :

```
  belongs_to :company
```

my edit method in controller :

```
  def edit
    // i get company id with before_action
    @company.build_licence
  end
```

my new method in controller  :

```
  def new
    @company = Company.new
    @company.build_licence
  end
```

new/create methods work great with this code. But edit form does not fill nested model inputs.

Comment: as the answer said, when you use `build_licence` it adds a new empty license, thats why you dont see any data in it. all you need is to set `@company`, and i guess you do it on some other action - so you edit method should be empty and it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say it doesn't fill the model inputs... but you are using `build_license` which creates a new, empty one every time... even if one exists already... it will blow the existing one away.

You might need to do something like:

```
def edit
  // i get company id with before_action
  @company.licence || @company.build_licence
end
```